# How to refresh the custom LWC when record is created from related tab

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, refresh

I have Obj_A and Obj_B.
In the record page, I have a related tab(Obj_B) from which I create new record. In the same record page(Obj_A), I have a custom LWC embedded. Now If I create a record using New button from the related tab(Obj_B), I want to refresh the custom LWC(Obj_A).
Is there a way to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve that you can use combination of Platform Events + empApi.
You need to define Platform Event in setup.
Platform event can be send from apex (so in your case trigger), flows and process builders.

To receive that event you need to use empAPI in your LWC.

Copypaste from the documentation:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { subscribe, unsubscribe, onError, setDebugFlag, isEmpEnabled } from 'lightning/empApi';

export default class EmpApiLWC extends LightningElement {
    channelName = '/event/Test__e'; 
    isSubscribeDisabled = false;
    isUnsubscribeDisabled = !this.isSubscribeDisabled;

    subscription = {};

    // Tracks changes to channelName text field
    handleChannelName(event) {
        this.channelName = event.target.value;
    }

    // Initializes the component
    connectedCallback() {       
        // Register error listener       
        this.registerErrorListener();      
    }

    // Handles subscribe button click
    handleSubscribe() {
        // Callback invoked whenever a new event message is received
        const messageCallback = function(response) {
            console.log('New message received: ', JSON.stringify(response));
            // Response contains the payload of the new message received
        };

        // Invoke subscribe method of empApi. Pass reference to messageCallback
        subscribe(this.channelName, -1, messageCallback).then(response => {
            // Response contains the subscription information on subscribe call
            console.log('Subscription request sent to: ', JSON.stringify(response.channel));
            this.subscription = response;
            this.toggleSubscribeButton(true);
        });
    }

    // Handles unsubscribe button click
    handleUnsubscribe() {
        this.toggleSubscribeButton(false);

        // Invoke unsubscribe method of empApi
        unsubscribe(this.subscription, response => {
            console.log('unsubscribe() response: ', JSON.stringify(response));
            // Response is true for successful unsubscribe
        });
    }

    toggleSubscribeButton(enableSubscribe) {
        this.isSubscribeDisabled = enableSubscribe;
        this.isUnsubscribeDisabled = !enableSubscribe;
    }

    registerErrorListener() {
        // Invoke onError empApi method
        onError(error => {
            console.log('Received error from server: ', JSON.stringify(error));
            // Error contains the server-side error
        });
    }
}
```

With this part of html:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="EmpApi Example" icon-name="custom:custom14">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <p>Use the buttons below to subscribe and unsubscribe to a streaming channel!</p>
            <lightning-input label="Channel Name" value={channelName}
                onchange={handleChannelName}></lightning-input>
            <lightning-button variant="success" label="Subscribe" title="Subscribe"
                onclick={handleSubscribe} disabled={isSubscribeDisabled}
                class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
            <lightning-button variant="destructive" label="Unsubscribe" title="Unsubscribe"
                onclick={handleUnsubscribe} disabled={isUnsubscribeDisabled}
                class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Documentation source [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation)

Comment: Thanks for your help ! It worked